# H2 In-memory database not showing console in weblogic but shows in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, h2, weblogic12c

I am using H2 In-memory database for a spring-boot application with gradle.
I am able to see the console when i run in Tomcat but i am unable to see the h2-console when i deploy on weblogic. It works but i want to see the h2-console to do some CRUD operations.
Here is my application.properties for H2:
spring.datasource.h2.console.enabled=true

I can see the console at this endpoint for Tomcat:

http://localhost:8080/../../api/h2-console

But i cannot see the console at the below endpoint for weblogic:

http://localhost:7001/../../api/h2-console
Whitelabel Error Page

I am thinking that it could be a simple property file change. But my research could not find anything related. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion or help on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Spring Boot devtools maven dependency and repackaging your application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```